# JBoss Fuse Hello World - Missing Manifest issue

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, jboss-developer-studio

I'm trying to follow the steps outlined in the hello world program for Red Hat JBoss Fuse: https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/hello-world/

When I go to deploy the bundle I get an error message "Unable to retrieve the bundle details for deployment. Possible reason is a missing or invalid Manifest."

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's the trace I get from the pom.xml:

> org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Internal error in
>   maven-bundle-plugin
>       at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute(ManifestPlugin.java:119)
>       at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:387)
>       at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:378)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
>       at org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.felix.internal.MavenBundlePluginConfigurator$1.build(MavenBundlePluginConfigurator.java:125)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calc manifest failed,
>   state=
>
> {pom.id=com.mycompany:camel-blueprint-cbr:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,
>   file.encoding.pkg=sun.io,
>   org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.2,JavaSE/compact1-1.8,JavaSE/compact2-1.8,JavaSE/compact3-1.8,JRE-1.1,J2SE-1.2,J2SE-1.3,J2SE-1.4,J2SE-1.5,JavaSE-1.6,JavaSE-1.7,JavaSE-1.8,
>   env.PROMPT=$P$G,
>   osgi.framework=file:/c:/Users/z1234567/devstudio/studio/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.3.v20170209-1843.jar,
>   version.maven-bundle-plugin=3.2.0, java.home=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre,
>   eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench, pom.contributors=[],
>   org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpoints.toggleFactoriesUsed=true,
>   project.build.developers=[], project.description=Camel Content-Based
>   Router Example,
>   pom.pomFile=C:\Users\z1234567\JBOSS_studio_workspace\fuse-camel-cbr\pom.xml,
>   java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\endorsed,
>   project.build.groupId=com.mycompany, env.USERNAME=z1234567,
>   sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1,
>   java.vendor.url=*******java.oracle.com/, env.COMPUTERNAME=AAAAAAAB,
>   env.=C:=C:\Users\z1234567\devstudio, pom.profiles=[],
>   maven-symbolicname=com.mycompany.camel-blueprint-cbr,
>   java.version=1.8.0_121,
>   osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation.default=true, osgi.os=win32,
>   osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true,

...

Answer (score 2):

based on the error that is provided, it seems that you hit a bug in Tycho m2e integration with maven-bundle-plugin (a bug which was reported for sure but that i'm not able to find again)
A workaround which is working most of the time consists in refreshing the Maven project (Alt+F5)

regards,

Comment: I've tried updating the project, but still run into the same error. Any other ideas? Thanks